# How to package common DLLs to to Azure Container Registry and refer them to multiple apps

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have a specific requirement on referring common .DLL files to multiple applications running on Azure Container instances/App Services. What I want to do is to package all the .DLL files to one docker image and put them in a container registry or docker hub and use them in the application runtime of other applications as common libraries. This is required to migrate to the cloud from the following architecture in an on-prem IIS server. Is this possible to do in Azure using a Container registry - how to approach this?

[image]

Comment: How about storing the common dlls in blob storage ? Found a similar discussion here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230275/hosting-a-shared-dll-in-azure

Comment: This scenario is not possible.  The answer from David in the question referenced by Vineet is your best bet but it means that you'll have some refactoring to do.  Why not instead embrace the cloud model and wrap these DLLs into APIs?

Comment: Packaging the DLLs into a container is easy. Deploying and accessing the DLLs from the container is problematic. Package the DLLs or the source to build the DLLs into a distribution package. C#/.NET has NuGet. PHP, Python, and other languages also have packaging systems. By using a packaging system the dependencies can be automatically retrieved, installed, and set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using Azure Container Instances. I deployed both base DLL library and the projects that are referring to the DLL library separately in an Azure Container Registry and used relative paths in the DOCKER file inside the project to the DLL image. So worked smoothly.
[image]

[image]